# Custom Constraint Validation as service for entity

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm trying to set a custom constrait validation to one of my entities, the constrait validation needs to check the datatable to check and validate the field.

I followed this link: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/validation/custom_constraint.html but it don't say how to set the constrait validation to my entity with YAML.

Setting the constrait validation as class, symfony throws me an error saying that that class need to be passed an instance of EntityManager.

Here is my Validator:

```
namespace Acme\BundleibBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class IsNotDayOff extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $em;

    public $message = 'Impossible the send this day.';

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $repository = $em->getRepository('AcmeRibBundle:DayOff');

        $isDayOff = $repository->findOneByDate($value);

        if ($isDayOff) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();

        }
    }
}
```

And here my service config:

```
validator.is_not_day_off:
    class: Acme\Bundle\RibBundle\Validator\Constraints\IsNotDayOff
    attributes:
        - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: "validator.is_not_day_off" }
```

I also try this:

```
validation.yml
Acme\Bundle\RibBundle\Entity\Address:
        properties:
            deliveryDate:
                - validator.is_not_day_off: ~
```

But throws and Exception too.

Some help pls?

Comment: Just replace `attributes` to `arguments` in your service configuration.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake, but the error persists

Comment: What is method validateBy() of constraint return? And which version of Symfony are you used?

Comment: I haven't validateBy() method, it is mandatory? And i'm using Symfony 2.8

Comment: Can you please provide the error or Exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you only have a validator and you're trying to apply it as a constraint on your property.

You should have to distincts class:

your constraint that appears in validation.yml

```
class IsNotDayOff extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'your error message';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        //return your validator class
    }
}
```

your validator you have to declare as a service in services.yml

```
class IsNotDayOffValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    //your own logic...
}
```

Comment: You're right! I did it yesterday and works perfectly. Thanks!